# How can I prevent MATLAB from automatically modifying .dat file variable names upon import using the dataset function?

Tags: matlab, variables, dataset, identifier, naming-conventions

So, I currently have a MATLAB script that does stuff with data and then, using a template .dat file, creates about 20 more .dat files with only a single column being changed (I've been using the `dataset` and `export` functions to read and write the files, respectively). The program that will use the .dat files, ExperimentBuilder, requires that the headers have names that start with dollar signs (for example: `$image`). However, when I use the dataset function in MATLAB to import the template file, I get this warning:

```
Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers.
```

It then replaces all the dollar signs in the variables to `x_` (for example, `x_image`), which would be fine if it would let me change it back to the $ format. But whenever I try to using  `set` , it just gives me this warning again and reverts it back to `x_`, which is unreadable by ExperimentBuilder.

I know I could just do a quick copy and paste on each file with the original headings, but I would like to know if there's a way to fix this problem in the actual code.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think there is a way to have these symbols as variable names, because, as the message tells you, they are not `valid MATLAB identifiers`. Why would you need a variable name with `$` in it (if Matlab cannot handle it)? Please describe the application you intend to use these variables with.

Comment: @Schorsch Well, I realize MATLAB can't interpret them, so it's fine if MATLAB converts it before writing back to a new .dat file, but after the script is applied I'd like for them to be in the format that ExperimentBuilder uses. ExperimentBuilder (a somewhat proprietary psychology experiment-creating software) can use a .dat file as a data source (it prompts you to select one prior to running an experiment). If it's not in the right format (with the $ in front of the heading name), it gets an error and doesn't run.

Comment: So your question is about the `fprintf`-function? How do you create that *new* .dat file? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to say that I have already created those new files using the `export` function. Everything works fine except for MATLAB's changing of the variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is the MATLAB `database` uses the header names to provide access to the columns by name, this is why the header names must be valid identifiers (`isvarname()` states that it must starts with a letter, and contains only valid alphanumeric characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

The easiest solution would be manually write the header line yourself (including names starting with `$`), while separately exporting the data without the headers:

```
export(ds, ..., 'WriteObsNames',false)
```

(Note that `dataset.export` overwrites files by default, so you'll have to `export` first, then prepend the header line at the beginning of the file. Or if you're comfortable modifying MATLAB own functions, then go `edit dataset.export` and change the `fopen` mode from overwrite `'wt'` to append `'at'` mode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks like manually writing it in would be the easiest way to go...but if I were to write a way to have MATLAB prepend the headers after exporting without the headers, what would be a simple way to do so?

Comment: an easy solution would be to use the system shell tools for concatenating files. So if you write the headers to `headers.txt` and the data is exported to `data.txt` (without the header line), you could combine the two as: `cat headers.txt data.txt > out.txt`. On Windows DOS, you could do the same using the `type` or `copy` commands: http://superuser.com/questions/111825